# Python - Split same day (date) into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, date

I'm using pandas, I have one column attendance timestamp data (Date).
I want to split the same day values into (InTime) and (OutTime) columns.

```
df = df[['Date']]

Date
Thu 1/09 9:10 AM
Thu 1/09 6:10 PM
Fri 2/09 9:04 AM
Fri 2/09 6:02 PM
```

I'm trying to achieve the following result.

```
In Time            OutTime
Thu 1/09 9:10 AM   Thu 1/09 6:10 PM 
Fri 2/09 9:04 AM   Fri 2/09 6:02 PM
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help. Problem is that the data is not as neat as it should be. Missing In-Time/Out-Time or near-duplicate records. + I'm a basic python user and I couldn't even understand the code to modify it for my requirements.

I'm requesting to have a look at the complete scenario and my attempts so far to achieve the desired result.

It's an attendance machine data where the user has either forgot to mark the attendance or machine created a duplicate entry for longer thumb impression. So the provided code jumbles up the AM and PM columns wherever it finds any duplicate or missing record.

The sample data looks like this:

```
User    Date
11  Thu 1/09 9:10 AM
3   Thu 1/09 9:10 AM
4   Thu 1/09 9:10 AM
2   Thu 1/09 9:23 AM
5   Thu 1/09 9:39 AM    
... ...   ...

12  Fri 30/09 5:55 PM
5   Fri 30/09 6:01 PM
6   Fri 30/09 6:04 PM
11  Fri 30/09 6:09 PM
```

I'm trying to create multiple `.csv` files for every user where In and Out timestamps are in separate columns **including empty records for non-consecutive days** so it could be pasted in an already-created Excel template.

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', encoding="utf-8", sep=',')
df = df[["User", "Date"]]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df,
                         columns=['User', 'Date'])
users = {
    'falcon': 2,
    'charlie': 3,
}

for username, ID in users.items():
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['User'] == ID]
    df = df[['Date']]
    df.to_csv(username + ".csv", encoding="utf-8", sep=',', header=False, index=False)
```

Result:

```
Thu 1/09 9:10 AM
Thu 1/09 6:11 PM
Fri 2/09 9:18 AM    # Missing PM
Sat 3/09 10:44 AM
Sat 3/09 6:00 PM
Mon 5/09 9:22 AM    # Missing PM
Tue 6/09 9:09 AM
Tue 6/09 6:25 PM
Wed 7/09 9:18 AM
Wed 7/09 6:33 PM
```

I'm trying to split these dates so that the entries with AM / PM are separated in their respected columns (including empty records for missing dates).

Comment: The sample data in the .csv and original text file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qs9qixf4grx5tul/python-split-dates-data.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the csv you have shared, it is clear that the are problems with the Date format (it is not consistent but it is not a problem for now) and with duplicated entries.

Note that there are rows missing the AM times and rows missing the PM times. Assuming that a User gets IN in the morning and OUT in the afternoon, I have made a simple loop that checks for each user the IN and OUT times and add "missing" in case of missing entries. A dataframe is generated for each user and then all the dataframes are concatenated. Is up to you to sort the final dataframe if you want, but you have to standardize the data format first. I didn't do this step since it is not part of the question and the problem can be solved without it.

```
import pandas as pd

input_csv = '/Users/alec/Downloads/python-split-dates-data/sandbox.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(input_csv)
print(df)

     User              Date
0      11  Sun 9/01 9:10 AM
1       3  Sun 9/01 9:10 AM
2       4  Sun 9/01 9:10 AM
3       2  Sun 9/01 9:23 AM
4       5  Sun 9/01 9:39 AM
..    ...               ...
339    12   9/30/22 5:55 PM
340     5   9/30/22 6:01 PM
341     6   9/30/22 6:04 PM
342    11   9/30/22 6:09 PM
343     4   9/30/22 6:19 PM
[344 rows x 2 columns]



cleaned_df = []
for user, group in df.drop_duplicates().groupby('User'):
    am = [] #store AM entries
    pm = [] #store PM entries
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        if row.Date.endswith('AM'):
            am.append(row.Date)
        elif row.Date.endswith('PM'):
            while len(am) <= len(pm):
                am.append('missing IN') #add missing
            while len(pm) < len(am)-1:
                pm.append('missing OUT') #add missing
            pm.append(row.Date)
    assert len(am) == len(pm) #double check data is consistent
    _df = pd.DataFrame({'User':[user]*len(am), 'IN':am, 'OUT':pm})
    cleaned_df.append(_df)
    
new_df = pd.concat(cleaned_df)
print(new_df)

    User                IN               OUT
0      2  Sun 9/01 9:23 AM  Sun 9/01 5:55 PM
1      2  Wed 9/02 9:20 AM  Wed 9/02 5:46 PM
2      2  Wed 9/03 9:24 AM  Wed 9/03 5:46 PM
3      2  Mon 9/05 9:23 AM  Mon 9/05 5:40 PM
4      2  Thu 9/06 9:26 AM  Thu 9/06 5:49 PM
..   ...               ...               ...
0     12        missing IN   9/23/22 5:54 PM
1     12  9/27/22 10:24 AM   9/27/22 1:34 PM
2     12   9/28/22 9:01 AM   9/28/22 5:51 PM
3     12   9/29/22 9:08 AM   9/29/22 5:52 PM
4     12   9/30/22 9:16 AM   9/30/22 5:55 PM

[182 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I quickly tested the code and it seems to work. I'm a bit occupied to decide the accepted answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the user doesn't log out today and log in tomorrow, you'll get a silent error: there will be two different days in one record for `IN` and `OUT`.

Comment: @Vitalizzare I will double check but I think the code is taking care of it. For each day it expects an IN and OUT.  Note the `assert len(am) == len(pm)` There are two while-loops one is checking for missing INs, one for missing OUTs.

Comment: Suppose we have this part in the data: `["Thu 1/09 9:10 AM", "Sat 3/09 6:00 PM"]`. Do you expect to get two records for each day, or one with __Sep, 1__ in the `IN` column and __Sep, 3__ in the `OUT'?

Comment: 2 records. `["Thu 1/09 9:10 AM - IN", "Thu 1/09 missing OUT"]` and `["Sat 3/09 - missing IN"], "Sat 3/09 6:00 PM - OUT"]`. I will double check, now I can't. But it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with [**`pandas.DataFrame.join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and [**`pandas.DataFrame.shift`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) :

```
new_df = (
            df.add_suffix('_In_time')
              .join(df.shift(-1).add_suffix('_Out_time'))
              .iloc[::2]
         )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(new_df)

       Date_In_time     Date_Out_time
0  Thu 1/09 9:10 AM  Thu 1/09 6:10 PM
1  Fri 2/09 9:04 AM  Fri 2/09 6:02 AM
```

Comment: Many thanks. Almost there. The data has missing or duplicate entries for the AM and PM values. If we could insert blank values for the missing ones. In fact I also need blank spaces for non-consecutive days.

Answer (score 3):

#### The code

*Note: This code is written with original post in mind (see the Update section below).*

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from dateutil.parser import parse

data = '''User,Date
1,Thu 1/09 9:10 AM
1,Thu 1/09 6:11 PM
1,Fri 2/09 9:18 AM
1,Sat 3/09 10:44 AM
1,Sat 3/09 6:00 PM
1,Mon 5/09 9:22 AM
1,Tue 6/09 9:09 AM
1,Tue 6/09 6:25 PM
1,Wed 7/09 9:18 AM
1,Wed 7/09 6:33 PM
2,Thu 1/09 9:13 AM
2,Thu 1/09 6:10 PM
2,Fri 2/09 9:10 AM
2,Fri 2/09 6:10 PM
2,Sat 3/09 10:40 AM
2,Sat 3/09 5:55 PM
2,Tue 6/09 6:21 PM
2,Wed 7/09 9:10 AM
2,Wed 7/09 6:30 PM
'''

df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(data), 
    parse_dates=[1], 
    date_parser=lambda x: parse(x, dayfirst=True)
)

df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.date
df['InOut'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%p').map({'AM':'In time', 'PM':'Out time'})
output = df.pivot(index=['User','Day'], columns='InOut',values='Date')

users = df['User'].unique()
days = pd.date_range(start=df['Day'].min(), end=df['Day'].max(), freq='D')
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([users, days])
output = output.reindex(index, fill_value=pd.NA)

for user_id, group in output.groupby(level=0):
    group.to_csv(
        f'user_{user_id}.csv', 
        index=False, 
        date_format='%a %d/%m %I:%M %p'
    )
```

#### Notes

Let's say we have some data in a csv format of this kind:

| User | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 42 | Mon 5/9 10:50 AM |

Here, the user contains a user id, and the date's parts are Weekday, Day/Month, Hour:Minute, AM/PM (the year is 2022 by default, ie. the current year).

We can read these data with `pandas.read_csv` and parse date values with `dateutil.parser.parse` with a parameter `dayfirst=True`, which [is False by default](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parserinfo) (`dateutil` is installed as [a dependency of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html?highlight=dateutil#dependencies)):

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(data), 
    parse_dates=[1], 
    date_parser=lambda x: parse(x, dayfirst=True)
)
```

Now we have a correct type of `df['Date']` and can apply to it a subset of [Series.dt functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html?#pandas-series-dt):

```
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.date
df['InOut'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%p').map({'AM':'In time', 'PM':'Out time'})
```

Here, `df['Date'].dt.strftime('%p')` returns AM or PM time value which we use to map time as In or Out value, see [Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for detailes.

With these additional columns we can obtain a close to desired output [by pivoting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
output = df.pivot(index=['User','Day'], columns='InOut',values='Date')
```

Next step is to insert missing days. For this purpose we can apply [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html?highlight=reindex#pandas.DataFrame.reindex), replacing the original indexes with wider ones. For the latter we create a [multyindex from the product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html?highlight=from_product#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product) of unique users and the date interval from the very first to the last possible date:

```
users = df['User'].unique()
days = pd.date_range(
    start=df['Day'].min(),   # from the first day
    end=df['Day'].max(),     # to the last possible day
    freq='D'                 # with frequency 1 day
)   
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([users, days])
output = output.reindex(index, fill_value=pd.NA)
```

Now we have this output data:
[image: output scheenshot]

To save them in a desired format as a csv-file per user, lets group `output` by the first level of its multy index and save [each group in a for-loop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__):

```
for user_id, group in output.groupby(level=0):
    group.to_csv(
        f'user_{user_id}.csv', 
        index=False, 
        date_format='%a %d/%m %I:%M %p'
    )
```

Here, we use `index=False` to drop indexes, and `'%a %d/%m %I:%M %p'` to save dates as `Weekday Day/Month Hour:Minute (AM/PM)`, see earlier mentioned [Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for detailes.

#### Update

After reading your *real* data, I've come to a conclusion that your actual problem is data unification and cleansing.

**About unification**

In the original post, dates are represented as `Thu 1/09 9:10 AM`, where *day* is going before *month*. But dates in your real data are always presented as *month* before *day*, e.g. `Sun 9/01 9:10 AM` which is September 1st, or `9/13/22 9:05 AM` which is September 13, or `2022-09-02 09:18:42` which is September 2nd. Which means that answers you get here may be not applicable to your *real* data.

Also you've represented dates in two different formats in one file: `Sun 9/01 9:10 AM` vs. `9/13/22 9:05 AM`, which will definitely cause serious problems with any answer to your question.

So in my opinion, the first thing you need to do is to unify the date format in your files.

**About cleansing**

I think it's not a question how to drop duplicates. As for *near-duplicate records* it's up to you how to define what is *near* and how those close records should be redused into one, be it *min*, *max*, *mean* etc. And I'm sure, that clening data is not a question for StackOverflow; it looks more like a task for a freelancer.

**About determining the time of arrival/departure by AM/PM**

This approach will cause errors as well. You have some records with arrival time after 12:00:00, or with departure time before 12:00:00. So any answer here will not cover those records. Maybe a better way would be to decide which difference is meaningful and on this basis extract the time of arrival and departure. You have to decide as well how to interpret the time around midday in case if it's a single time record for a user in some days.

Comment: I appreciate your approach and detailed explanation but somehow the code doesn't work on my `.csv` file. I'm attaching a zip file in dropbox. See the comment on the question.

I have a few questions as well. 

`1.` Is it possible to change the input date format e.g `2022-09-01 09:10:06` easily in this code. 

`2.` Is it possible to parse an unnamed first two columns out of a text file rather the CSV. (See attachment).

`3.` You didn't deal the username dictionary as filenames(alpha, falcon etc) in the output files.

`4.` The output files are expected without indexes and headers.

Comment: @NaveedAbbas Please, be more accurate in you questions. Also, I think that at this moment your questions are too wide to answer here. And please, try not to ask to accomplish some work which is more suitable at a freelance platform. As for your real data, see my feedback in the Update section.

Comment: You are right. Actually I didn't even know that the data would be so messed up. I tried to update the question but that opened another pandora box. Anyways, thanks a lot for your efforts. I have decided to split the bounty with you. I am a bit occupied to test the code for the accepted answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
# separate day from time
df[['Date1', 'Date2']] = df['Date'].str.split('(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', expand=True)

# create column with colnames for the new columns to be created by pivot
df['names'] = ['inTime', 'OutTime'] * (len(df)//2)
(df.pivot(index='Date1', columns='names', values='Date')
 .reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:,::-1])
```

Output:

```
names            inTime           OutTime
0      Fri 2/09 9:04 AM  Fri 2/09 6:02 PM
1      Thu 1/09 9:10 AM  Thu 1/09 6:10 PM
```

---

In case the dataset has not times ordered from earlier to later, then a solution might be the following:

```
# separate day from time
df[['Date1', 'Date2', 'Date3']] = df['Date'].str.split(
    '(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)|\s(?=.M$)', expand=True)

# this is needed if the times are no sorted in the initial dataset
df = df.sort_values(['Date1', 'Date3', 'Date2'])

# create column with colnames for the new columns to be created by pivot
df['names'] = ['inTime', 'OutTime'] * (len(df)//2)
(df.pivot(index='Date1', columns='names', values='Date')
 .reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:,::-1])
```

---

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

text = """
Date
Thu 1/09 9:10 AM
Thu 1/09 6:10 PM
Fri 2/09 9:04 AM
Fri 2/09 6:02 PM
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')

# separate day from time
df[['Date1', 'Date2']] = df['Date'].str.split('(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', expand=True)

# create column with colnames for the new columns to be created by pivot
df['names'] = ['inTime', 'OutTime'] * (len(df)//2)
df = (df.pivot(index='Date1', columns='names', values='Date')
      .reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:,::-1])
print(df)
```

Comment: Hi @PaulS, Great seeing you here with Python. Nice regex approach!

Comment: I remember you as nice guy from R StackOverflow! Now, I am trying to learn Python.

Comment: Thanks, you too! I am also trying to learn more Python. For sure I am going to learn a lot from your nice answers!

Comment: Thanks for your time but for some reason, your code doesn't work + I couldn't understand it either. (The regex is always diffiult for me and what the heck is double slashes? // we use it for comments in some languages :D

Comment: @NaveedAbbas: My code works fine for your initial problem, before you edited it -- your problem is now a *different* problem! The double slash in Python means integer division: [Python Double Slash](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-double-slash-operator-floor-division/#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20we%20can%20perform,floor()%20function.).

Comment: No, the first thing I tried was to paste your code and joined the line splits *carefully* and it thrown the following errors.
`df['names'] = ['inTime', 'OutTime'] * (len(df) // 2)`
and some from pandas coreframe `self._set_item(key, value)`
Core common `raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (48) does not match length of index (49)`

Comment: @NaveedAbbas: I have just added my complete code, which I have just tested -- it works well. You may want to try it out.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the code works after assuming few things but the result is not what I posted to get initially. Probably I'm getting a different output. https://i.postimg.cc/50kTcgYr/Screen-Shot-2022-10-04-at-3-30-25-PM.png

Comment: The code assumes that I have only one column in the csv format, whereas there are two columns (User, Date) I'm using pandas to get the Date Column.

Thanks again for your time. My data has duplication and missing entry issues and I thought I'd be able to deal it but I'm working to make it compatible first.

Comment: OK, @NaveedAbbas: I have now spotted the reason why you were not get the same output I am getting. Please, use my new updated complete code -- it should now work well on your end.

Comment: It works with a very limited data but as I stated above the code has inconsistencies, it shows this error `raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape") ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you use regex expressions, its scary for new-comers. BTW the code from user:abokey works even on the missing data. It switches the sides. Have a look at this. https://i.postimg.cc/1t7qSnKX/Screen-Shot-2022-10-04-at-4-06-40-PM.png

Answer (score 1):

another approach, convert the column to datetime and work with it. try:

```
df
    Date
0   Thu 1/09 9:10 AM
1   Thu 1/09 6:10 PM
2   Fri 2/09 9:04 AM
3   Fri 2/09 6:02 PM

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' 2022', format='%a %d/%m %H:%M %p %Y')
df['day'] = df['Date'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['Date'].dt.time

df.groupby('day').agg(InTime=('time', 'first'), OutTime=('time', 'last')).reset_index()

    day         InTime      OutTime
0   2022-09-01  09:10:00    06:10:00
1   2022-09-02  09:04:00    06:02:00
```

Comment: Thanks but the result I need requires the same date format. Maybe reformatting it after the code could produce the desired result.

Comment: i will add datetime formatting solution in my answer , what is the date format you need ?

Comment: Thanks. Any date/time format that can be easily recognized by excel. (9/30/22 9:05 AM) should work fine.